# Continuous Ball Fall perpetual motion machine

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, energy-conservation, perpetual-motion

[image]

Before I get to it. It must be absolutely clear that this ball will, when dropped from a great height, gain a velocity enough to spin this wheel connected a dynamo. And if there was a water contraption in which the ball would enter from the bottom and float to the top to fall again, would you create infinite power from electricity?

The anser is of course not, but I'm curious as to how.

edit:
[image]

Note. I am an idiot and the description of the picture above may not work. But usig the idea someone more knowledgable could come up with a better design and explain why that one would fail too.

So let me get two things out of the way. Line A is just a drawing gap for the ball to gain more speed and I could save space and Line B is the dynamo area.
What I'm trying to get at with the two lines next to the ball is that the air on both entrances of the water pipes are separated and the ball passes through a hole that can be only passed through by objects of high speed. and when it does it seels itslef up. Imagine it like a lucozade lid. The reason I'm separating the air is so that the top part can be air-tight so the water does not spill out. Note this was not drawn to scale. The ball will roll down the slope at the bottom gaining speed enough for its momentum to go under the water and float upwards in a north-east direction so it passes under the red wall. As it floats up the yellow line will push it out of the top hole back into the system.

If I'm wrong in my design, feel free to have a try.

Comment: The key is in how you think this "water contraption" would actually work. Can you be more detailed on that part?

Comment: Edited in he info

Comment: The ball would not float into the tube on the right side, since it has no horizontal momentum when it enters the water.

Comment: I said the slope would  give it it speed at the bottom (not to scale)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The slope at the bottom cannot impart any orizontal momentum to a ball supposedly floating. Simple as this. (The ball might of course reach the bottom. But if it is floatable in water, no horizontal Force can be attained).

---

Addition because it is still unclear to OP. If the ball is floatable/floating, no normal force from  the inclined plane acts on it. Thus, as the orizontal component of a null vector is zero as well, the inclined plane underwater is simpl not there, from a floating ball viewpoint. At best, the ball is bouncing and floating away from the impact point, like a launching of a ship. This should help.

Edit 2. The answer has been accepted however I would like to signal to readers the various comments that followed this and other answers. To this end I copy and paste here one of mines, dealing to the design in which the ball can indeed go "knock" to the door.

" So you could have draw the water just in the tower. Then the ball is pushed back due to  the water column pressure, accounting or not for water uncompressibiliy. *The ball will never have enough energy to overcome the P of the column water from which it is falling*. If the ball is supposed to float it cannot be. Note that your ideal door can only detect a threshold velocity and open accordingly. But not add energy. Water must spill out or at least stop the ball from entering."

Comment: Dude, the diagram is not to scale. The slope at the bottom will give it horizontal velocity.

Comment: Dude to get momentum down to the door you need something rolling down. Either your ball can or cannot float.  Look at inclined planes before attacking perpetual motion ;)

Comment: iT'S ON A SLOPE GOING DOWN. aT THE BOTTOM OF THE SLOPE IS WATTER. SINCE IT IS GATHERING SPEED DOWNWARDS AND TO THE RIGHT IT WILL PUSH DOWN INTO THE WATER RIGHTWARDS WHILS LOSING ITS DOWNWARDS VELOCITY DUE TO ITS BUOYANCE. I CBA TO TURN MY CAPS LOCK OFF, IM NOT SHOUTING.

Comment: So you could have draw the water just in the tower. Then the ball is pushed back due to column pressure, accounting or not for water uncompressibiliy. The ball will never have enough energy to overcome the P of the column water from which it is falling. If the ball is supposed to float it cannot be. Note that your ideal door can only detect a threshold velocity and open accordingly. But not add energy. Water spill out or at least stop the ball from entering.

Comment: Tomorrow I will perhaps complete the answer to include the latter case. The reason is fundamentally the same.  The incline does nothing here.

Comment: @yolo Whatever inclined slope you have to the left, the water will rise to fill it up.

Answer (score 3):

The tower of water you have is impossible. Note that the water level on the right tower is much higher than the water level on the left, where the ball lands. That isn't how water works: unless there is a gate or something holding the water in the tower, the level on the left will rise and on the right will fall until they are equal.

What is there is a gate on the tower of water? Well, it will have to open every time the ball goes up the tower. And each time, the ball can only float if a volume of water equal to the ball's volume displaces the ball. So each time it goes up the tower, one $V_{\rm ball}$ worth of water (or more) will leave it. Eventually, you reach the point that the water levels are equal and you can't extract any more energy from the system.

This doesn't achieve any extra energy- it just converts the gravitational energy of the water in the tower to kinetic energy of the ball. You may as well just run the water over the dynamo directly.

Comment: Basically what I waa going to sketch from a forcesy point of view.tge force exerted by a floating ballt dropping from a colii of water will never overcome the P of  same column to enter and dispaced it at its bottom. Ignoring incompressiblity an heavier ball could but stay there. Plus 1 anyway for having had said the same in a simple way tough the OP might still have the doubt why the videal door does not make the trick.

Comment: Whilst I understand your answer I was wondering if you could improve the design. (and I thought gravity wasn't energy)

Comment: @yolo No design will work to create energy from nothing. So the design can't really be improved. And any object held up against the force of gravity has gravitational potential energy.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is that the ball floating to the top doesn't happen "for free." In order for the ball to go underwater, it has to do work against the water (namely, it raises the water level a little, because water has to be displaced). If you extract energy from the ball each time on the way down, eventually the ball will not have enough kinetic energy at the bottom to actually displace enough fluid to go underwater, making it impossible to enter the tube.

In addition, what I explained above assumes that you're working in a fluid with zero viscosity, that you never collide with the walls, and that the energy extraction system is 100 percent efficient. None of these things are actually true in any real system, so even if you weren't extracting energy from the ball, the drag from movement through the fluid, energy losses due to colliding with the tube walls, and friction in your dynamo will eventually stop the machine.

Comment: So you are telling me that when the ball rolls down the slope over and over it will reach a point where it can't break through the water even with the slope giving it speed. And the dynamo is peing pushed and not slid against so the ball must always push through it because you can't expect soething falling towards a water wheel at high speed and not pushing through past itt.

Comment: Precisely. The friction I'm referring to is friction from rotation in the axle of the dynamo. But really, it doesn't matter precisely how your dynamo works - it can never be 100 percent efficient.

Comment: Of course. The hinge spinning will cause friction but assuming the ball is heavy enough to push past it once and the dynamo stops, it should be able to push past it twice as it is moving at the same speed as it was last time. I agree that the dynamo will break but not until the law of 'energy cannot be created' is broken.